# Nested Readonly Properties in Singleton Not Allowed?

Tags: qt, singleton, qml, qt-creator, readonly

I have a `Singleton` defined in `QML` code as:

```
pragma Singleton

import QtQuick 2.0

QtObject {
    /*
    readonly property QtObject example1: QtObject {
        readonly property int example1_1: 10
        readonly property int example1_2: 105
        readonly property int example1_3: 23
        readonly property int example1_4: 105
        readonly property int example1_5: 23
    }
    readonly property QtObject example2: QtObject {
        property int example2_1: 10
        property int example2_2: 105
        property int example2_3: 23
        property int example2_4: 105
        property int example2_5: 23
    }
    property QtObject example3: QtObject {
        readonly property int example3_1: 10
        readonly property int example3_2: 105
        readonly property int example3_3: 23
        readonly property int example3_4: 105
        readonly property int example3_5: 23
    }*/
    readonly property variant example4: {
        "example4_1": 10,
        "example4_2": 105,
        "example4_3": 23,
        "example4_4": 105,
        "example4_5": 23
    }
}
```

They do compile, however, `example1` has portions highlighted in red (see screenshot below) in `Qt Creator` seemingly indicating error.

[image]

This seems to be [a variant of this bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-41971), only with `readonly` recursively applied.  The above bug was fixed in [Qt 5.4](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/97930/).  Overall, though my code seems somewhat sluggish and has been crashing sporadically, so I'm wondering whether the approach of using `QtObject` might be creating some actual issues (my actual code is pretty big, so I'm not sure this is the culprit, or just a bystander).

I realize that `example4` is the best practice, as I'm declaring a series of `readonly property` values of a common, primitive type.

My questions are:

1. Is the highlighting of bad syntax a bug?
2. Are there any fundamental issues with declaring a `QtObject` with `readonly property` values?
3. Would any potential issues also apply to `example1` and `example2` even though they're viewed as syntactically correct by `Qt Creator`?

I'm using `Qt 5.7` and `Qt Creator 4.0.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your example work correctly when you run it? If yes it is likely a Qt Creator bug. The most important is that your program works correctly when you run it, not that Qt Creator displays things correctly. So test it and f**k Qt Creator if it indicates wrong things which are right.

Otherwise I would personally use JSON objects everywhere, just like your `example4` property.

Comment: Yep, it compiles fine...your advice is probably the soundest course... was just curious if there was some underlying reason to doubt the syntax. :)